# Android App Change language functionality code bug

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am creating an app which have functionality for user to **choose different language** so i created another app to test fuctionality there so idea is to create button in settings and save its **Language Value** and **onclick** the language changes and saving its value using shared preference there is **no error** in my code but the **language is not changing**. I am unable to figure please guys **any help is appreciated.** **HERE IS CODE FIRST MAIN THEN SETTINGS**:

```
TextView text;
    int language;
    SharedPreferences sh;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        sh=getSharedPreferences("lang", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        language=sh.getInt("language",0);
        Button Lang=(Button)findViewById(R.id.change);
        if(language==0)
        {
            text.setText("Germany");
        }
        else
        if(language==1)
        {
            text.setText("English");
        }
        Lang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,gauravmehra.testastro.Change.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

And **change Activity**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.change);
        changeLang=(Button)findViewById(R.id.changeLang);
        sh=getSharedPreferences("lang",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        language=sh.getInt("language",0);
        changeLang.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(language==0)
                {
                    language=1;
                    sh.edit().putInt("language",1);
                    sh.edit().commit();
                }
                else if(language==1)
                {
                    language=0;
                    sh.edit().putInt("language",0);
                    sh.edit().commit();
                }
                Intent i=new Intent(Change.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i figure  out what was the problem. I have tried above solutions but i think above methods cannot work in this problem so in my change methods i was previously doing

```
sh.edit().putInt("language",1);
sh.edit().commit();
```

but i think this thing doesn't work here so changed the line with this

```
 Editor editor=sh.edit();
 editor.putInt("language",1);
editor.commit();
```

and voila app now doing great. Hope it helps i am beginner in android.

Answer (score 0):

1. try to use **getApplicationContext()**
2. try to use the **Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS**

> getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("lang",Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS)

**Update:**
if your api level >=23

You must use **ContentProvider** instead of **SharedPreferences** in the multi process situation.

> public static final int **MODE_MULTI_PROCESS**

Added in API level 11
**This constant was deprecated in API level 23.**
MODE_MULTI_PROCESS does not work reliably in some versions of Android, and furthermore does not provide any mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications across processes. Applications should not attempt to use it. Instead, they should use an explicit cross-process data management approach such as **ContentProvider**.

ref:http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#MODE_MULTI_PROCESS

Comment: `MODE_MULTI_PROCESS` was deprecated in API level 23.

Comment: this also doesnt works i know it is deprecated and my app is currently below api 23 infact its 20 as currently making a prototype for language settings and i changed my line of code  sh=getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("lang",Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS); for both file.

still the language is germany

Comment: One of the reasons it was deprecated was because it did not always work. Also, it did not try try to handle in a nice way concurrent writes from multiple apps.

Comment: public static final int MODE_MULTI_PROCESS

Added in API level 11
**This constant was deprecated in API level 23.**
MODE_MULTI_PROCESS does not work reliably in some versions of Android, and furthermore does not provide any mechanism for reconciling concurrent modifications across processes. Applications should not attempt to use it. Instead, they should use an explicit cross-process data management approach such as **ContentProvider**.

Answer (score 0):

[EDITED]

You have what seems to be a copy/paste error.

In your "change Activity", you have this statement in 2 places:

```
                sh.edit().putInt("language",1);
```

You should instead use this in both places:

```
                sh.edit().putInt("language", language);
```

Or, even better:

```
        public void onClick(View v) {
            language = 1 - language;
            sh.edit().putInt("language", language); 
            sh.edit().commit(); 
            Intent i=new Intent(Change.this,MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

[OLD ANSWER - might still help others]

When calling getSharedPreferences(String name, int mode), the mode argument determines whether the stored values are private, or globally readable and/or writeable.

MODE_PRIVATE was used in the app that originally stored the data. That means that no other apps have any access to that data.

You should be aware that the other 2 main modes have been deprecated since API Level 17, though, since they open up security holes. Also, MODE_MULTI_PROCESS was deprecated in API level 23 because it did not work reliably. So, there is really no good way to use a SharedPreference between apps.

If you don't really need to share data between apps, you should put both activities in the same app. But, if the 2 activities are in [different processes](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html#Processes) or you really need two apps, then you should consider having the first app implement either a ContentProvider or Service to provide the shared data. For example, you could use a [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/FileProvider.html).

Or, in general you could just pass the data between the 2 apps as [extras in the `Intent`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html#Building) you pass to `startActivity()`, and that would not require use of SharedPreferences at all.

Comment: hey cyber thanks for replying the current scenario is use this thing in same  app and using shared preference is because when users changes language from language button and after closing the app, when next time he opens the language will be the one he choosen last time

Comment: If you still have the same problem with both activities in the same app, do the two activities happen to be in different processes?

Comment: No actually the case is like using rss feed calling api every time you opens the app so if user goes to settings activity which have other things also and choose english and next time he opens the app(i will do it programmatically to restart activity) he will get feed in english otherwise feed will come in germany which is default it is as simple as that please read my code

Comment: See my updated answer. You had what seems to be a copy/paste error.